# What would be the societal effects of a human subspecies that can live for 200-500 years, and look young until death?

Tags: society, social-norms

The basic conceit is this: the human subspecies in question has some magical abilities, and thanks to them every single member of their society has extreme ability to stay young and healthy until death. They typically live for 100-250 years, but particularly fit members can live for twice that before their bodies just "shut down".

In between that time, they stay in the peak of human health. Disease, malnutrition,and other things may slow them down, but they will ALWAYS recover to full health. They also have an advanced economy that must be considered much more advanced than ours. Their society, otoh, is backwards due to the above features causing older generations to last longer.

However, what should be the societal sideffects for this other than the obvious benefits of an eternally fit working class? An economic boon that may be, but I realise this won't avoid other problems. What could be some of them?

Edit: added that I want answers as to the "societal" side effects.

Comment: It means that they have a complex economy with everything from AI and robots down to artificial meat. Think South Korea on steroids, except on an area the size of Asia.

Comment: Did they only recently acquire this longevity, or had they naturally evolved with it?

Comment: They have had it forever. "Forever" meaning 10,000 years,when they were first created. The specific state I am discussing has been around for just a fifth of that tho.

Comment: Are there any visible differences between individuals who are 20 and 220 years old?

Comment: No. Once you're an adult and stop growing, natural change also stops. No ageing, ever.

Comment: Are they fertile the entire time? How many kids would they have? Population growth might be absolutely wild, unless they manage their families very very differently than we do. Family reunions would be ENORMOUS.

Comment: And the older ones should generally end up fabulously wealthy with hundreds of years for investment to grow. Moving up the corporate ladder would be a lot harder, with less retirement at the top. Because until your investments keep up with your desired lifestyle, couldn’t  retire. But also, healthcare is often a huge cost in retirement. Then again, you might go on an occasional 20 year sabbatical and then go back to work when funds start to get low.

Comment: That reminds me somewhat of Altered Carbon's Meths.

Comment: @EricG Very few companies last 200 years regardless of how good they are at doing what they do because technology changes so much in that stretch of time.  So, yes, you might become fabulously wealthy by the time you are 100, but you could easily lose that entire fortune by the time you are 200.  Think about how pro-athletes rise and fall in fortunes in a single life time, and what we think of as normal investment could ebb and flow along the same lines, just at a different scale.

Comment: Just normal investment in a mutual fund would make you filthy rich on that time scale. You don’t have to have any good ideas of your own and get rich. Assuming a peaceful society anyway. This one could easily get resource hungry and go to war all the time.

Comment: They are almost always at war, but the society in the mainland is stable enough. So it could work.

Comment: Have the colonized the solar system? I’m legit fascinated by this question. Can I ask what you are working on?

Comment: @EricG ...Well...let's just say they have a metric ton of planets (as in,thousands if they wished, though they do not need most) under them. Their universe doesn't quite work like ours, so answering the question directly is not possible. Also, just a hobby project.

Comment: Hello Thales. This Q is probably going to get closed. I haven't VTC'd, but if you had more rep, I would have. This is an open-ended all-answers-have-equal-value question, which the [help/dont-ask] asks that you don't ask. Stack Exchange's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer, and you've given no criteria that could be used to identify or judge a best answer. We need to convert this from an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) to an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609).

Comment: It is a very interesting premise, but you need to focus your question a bit. Are you looking for economic consequences? political? psychological? or maybe something else? Perhaps it would be better to ask several questions dealing with each aspect you are interested in.

Comment: If you want to know about possible societal effects you need to provide a bit more information about the social structure, customs, and traditions. Is it an individualistic society? a collectivist society? Do they respect elders? Are individual merits more important? What is the family structure: Clan, multi-generational, nuclear? Does age affect power? What kind of power (money, politics, respect, etc.)? Once you have more details we can help you to fill in the blanks and missing connections.

Comment: @EricG And yes, they are fertile all the while.

Answer (score 5):

**Famine.**

Because the population will expand rapidly.  Let us set historical realism aside and just consider math.   Consider a stable human population where each man and woman have remarkable restraint or access to contraception and have 2 offspring by age 40.  The offspring are their replacements.  The population is stable in size.

Consider now your 500 year olds.  Each couple also produces 2 offspring.  But the parents do not die and get out of the way.  They live on.  Thus every 40 years the population doubles.  A population starting at 1000 will be 2 million in 400 years, and the old folks have another 100 years to go before they start dying.

Historically humans had more than 2 offspring, and population increase was controlled by starvation and disease.  Your people are durable to starvation and disease.  But with population pressure like this something bad is going to happen.

Land that can feed 1000 will not be able to feed 1000000 no matter how good looking they are.  Either there will be serious emigration of these long lived folks and expansion of their territory, or reproduction must very infrequent.  Like once, or none.

Comment: Given that this civilization is 10,000 years old, we may assume that they somehow learned how to control their population.

Comment: They do have the ability to feed their own population, as my comment on their advanced technology implies.

Comment: You need to figure out the population question. Either they can host people with wild density (they could easily have 100 Billion people on Earth) or there are some really big hang ups over who is allowed to have kids.

Comment: @EricG - those are the options and the one chosen has big ramifications for the question.

Comment: Yeah. I meant “you” as in OP. I was going to type this up. The third option might be massive social upheaval when they get resource strapped and millions or billions die in the wars. Or maybe they colonize the solar system and beyond. But population growth is the big question the OP has to deal with.

Comment: 1) The OP states that most live only 100-250 years, only particularly fit individuals live to 500. 2) You assume that these people have the same family patterns as us which is unreasonable since the OP's society exists for 10 000 years already. It is more likely that their marriage and child-bearing ages are higher than what we have. So, there is no population doubling every 40 years. 3) This society is almost always at war (the OP said so in comments). 4) The OP states that they have access to a multitude of planets (see comments). *Overpopulation and famine are highly unlikely*.

Comment: @Otkin - you have many more insights into the ways of these people than I did.  Maybe you should post an answer laying them out?

Comment: @Willk I am unsure what the OP is asking for. There is also not enough information for me to write an answer I would be content with. So I can only discuss weaker points in answers of people who are braver than me. No offence or disrespect intended.

Answer (score 5):

### Your idea that they would be backwards is mistaken

[Planck's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_principle) only applies to humans because we get old, not because we live for a long time. As people get older, declining health changes how we treat ourselves, our societies, and our resources.  Consider the following:

- [Studies suggest that old people are more likely to avoid increased risks, but just as likely to exploit an increased gain](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3852157/).  This means age does not make you incapable of taking risks, but that there are factors the make you less likely to take certain risks. One likely explanation for this phenomenon is that [getting old physically makes you less likely to bounce back](https://advancedtissue.com/2014/11/age-effect-wound-healing/) from high-risk high-reward endeavors; so, you become less experimental in regards to risk.  When you are young getting hurt is of little consequence because your experience is that you always make a full recovery.  Older people often struggle with injuries from many years ago which they could have made a full recovery from when they were younger.  This means that biology creates stronger punishments for risk as you get older by reducing out ability to heal.
- [Getting old makes your neural plasticity decrease](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fnagi.2011.00005/full) making it harder to learn new things and perform new behaviors.  This is a biological hindrance where your brain physically rearranges itself as you get older.  If you could physically lock your body in time, then your brain's configuration would stay that of a younger person and remain more acceptable to new ideas.
- You become resistant to taking the time to learn new skills even if you could because you no longer have a long road ahead of you to make use of those skills.  Research into [Human explore/exploit patterns](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2014-44776-001) shows that given more future time, humans are more prone to deliberately explore new options.
- Your overall motivation to do anything outside of your routine decreases because you just don't have the energy you once did to maintain your routine PLUS the extra stuff.

Because your people do not get old, they will live a lot like people do in their early 20s, but for much longer.  This will give them far more time to explore new ideas, reinvent themselves, and challenge the status quo.  Since your society would be so full of youthful energy and people living for very long times, social values would likely shift more towards celebrating people who continue to change over time.

- Marriage & child rearing would go from a whole-life-commitment to a term-commitment; so, you could get married, raise some kids, and then just move on with your remaining 150 years to do other things. Because the bulk of your healthy adult life is no longer reserved for child rearing, you'd spend most of your adult life with very little responsibilities to other people allowing one to do more or less whatever, just like most people do in their early 20s.
- [Older people are actually more likely to switch career paths than younger people](https://business.linkedin.com/talent-solutions/blog/2015/09/how-a-persons-age-affects-why-they-change-jobs) suggesting that as we get older, the desire to reinvent yourself actually increases.  So, instead of the dominant force of 40-60 year old elders we have looking down at you for changing gears in life in our world, you'd have a lot more 70-200 year old elders supporting those changes because they know that it is something they've already felt compelled to do few times.  Just like we ask our kids "what will you be when you grow up?", very old people are more likely to ask their grown up kids "What will you be next?"
- Lastly, those few who do have the patience stick with a single path their whole lives could delve WAY deeper than we short lived people ever could which would actually accelerate the progress of society and technology because you would not need to wait for the next generation to finish re-learning what the was lost when the last generation died off.

So sure, if Albert Einstein were still alive and young today, maybe he would be making it harder for other physicists to take center stage in challenging his beliefs, but there are also the likelihoods that he would have pushed our knowledge of physics much further forward than we are right now... or the more likely scenario: he would have eventually gotten bored with physics and would now be a music teacher, plumber, or whatnot and his long life would have done nothing to prevent others from going in new directions anyway.

Otkin in comments has argued that comfortable and stable will push people in the direction of conservatism, and I agree that this will still be an active force in your society, but this society will also have many factors that our society does not have that will push it towards progressivism and innovation.  Overall, our own society containing younger people with older minds and bodies is likely more conservative than one with older people having younger minds and bodies.

Comment: I contest the idea that people wouldn’t be stuck in their ways just because the stay young. Some people would advance, yeah, but History has shown us plenty of young people are racist, violent, horrible pukes. Antivaxxers and climate change deniers come in all ages. 

Also, depending on what religion looks like in this society, having religious leaders turn over very rarely might lead to even less societal change. And again, I don’t think that is a direct function of aging, so much as habit.

Comment: Most of the things you list are psychological and not biological in nature. Is there any evidence to suggest that psychological phenomena associated with older age at least correlate with the condition of the brain matter?

Comment: @otkin Neural plasticity is biological.   Then there is in the field of learning the explore/exploit cycle which states that the longer you have left to exploit, the more reason you have to explore which is a major basis of many of the other statements made here.  As for the psychology aspect, pretty much everyone I know over 30 has had to give on certain things and change the way they address long term planning for no reason other than their bodies can't do what they used to do, and the need to prepare for a future where that only becomes more true.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Is risk aversion dependent on neural plasticity? Or has it more to do with psychological needs? I am also unsure if neural plasticity plays an important role in novelty seeking which, IIRC, is associated with genetics more than anything else. You make a good point about the bodily changes, but the changes in behaviour you mention can also result from accumulated experiences and changes in social status and obligations. One cannot live as freely and carefree when they have a stable job and a spouse.

Comment: @EricG The fact that young people can be racist, violent, antivaxing, climate change deniers only proves that turning over generations does not guarantee progress.  Young people generally adopt most of the ideas of their elders anyway, but they have the neural plasticity and a perspective of their own future to deviate more.  Also, putting people in positions of power does not prevent other people from unseating them.  Generally, societies change very slowly until a regime is changed by force.  Cruel kings raise cruel princes, but rebellions, elections, etc. happen much faster than old age.

Comment: @Otkin One of the points I've tried to make is when you live longer, a stable job and spouse become relative things.  Almost the entire healthy part of our adult lives is caught up in the family part of our lives, but now that we are seeing older people getting past this stage of life in good enough of health, we now often see "retires" starting second carriers based on what makes them happy after the kids moved out.  Those are people with deteriorating health, and just a few years left, but if you still had 150 years left in you after your kids are grown, the options would be limitless.

Comment: We are also starting to see people waiting longer to have kids with the expectation of a longer life.  Right now we see people waiting until almost 40 in some areas as the average time to start a family. If you thought you could wait 150 years before getting started, many people would make that choice as well.

Comment: Actually, another good example we are seeing for this is gay marriage.  Many gay marriages happen without any intention of children, and with little to no chance of an accidental child.  Based on the couples I know in their 30s and 40s, they still more or less have the same lifestyle other people had before kids.

Comment: Thank you for adding sources. TBH, I am still not entirely convinced but I understand your reasoning much better now and I think that you make excellent points (so, +1). I still think that you are a bit over-optimistic and discard intellectual laziness, preference for comfortable/stable/predictable life, and human tendencies of falling into habitual patterns of thinking and acting. However, my doubts cannot be proved or disproved because our society does not have eternally young people, so my speculations are destined to be left mere speculations.